# How to repeat an audio inside a function in Python with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, playsound

I need to repeat a sound every time I click at button, but it just play the audio one single time.

There is the code:

```py
from playsound import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Text to Speech")
window.geometry('640x480')

lbl = Label(window, text="Text to speech", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt = Entry(window, width=90)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl_texto = Label(window, text="O texto vai aqui")
lbl_texto.grid(column=0, row=2)

def clicked_btn():
    texto = txt.get()
    lbl_texto.configure(text= texto)
    language = 'pt-BR'
    obj = gTTS(text=texto, lang=language, slow=False)
    obj.save('audio.mp3')
    audio = 'audio.mp3'
    playsound(audio)
    window.update()

btn = Button(window, text="Executar", command=clicked_btn)
btn.grid(column=0, row=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Tried change the playsound module to OS but nothing happened.

Comment: Your code runs fine...  what is the issue?

Comment: @Alexander, I cant run the sound twice. I have to close the program and run again. I want to play the sound every time I click in button.

Comment: When I run your code that is exactly what it does.

Comment: @Alexander, here I have to close and run again to repeat the audio. What is your python version?

Comment: python version 10.something